# Camel Case JsonObject array in sql server2016

Tags: json.net, sql-server-2016

I am returning Json from SqlServer 2016 using "For JSON AUTO" My op is like this

```
"[{\"Id\":3,\"SId\":\"5801\",\"Name\":\"Pizza\",\"Type\":\"Error\"}]"
```

I am deserializing data using below code

```
 public Someclass GetData(int Id)
    {
        using (var dataContext = new DataContext(_connectionString))
        {
               var serializer = new JsonSerializerSettings()
               {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
               };
            var dataArray = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<string>(query.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();
            dynamic obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(dataArray , serializer);

            return obj
        }
    }
```

In obj object i don't get camelcased data.It is of below format

```
 "{[{"Id":3,SId":"5801","Name":"Pizza","Type":"Error"}]}"
```

Since my datastructure holding json result is dynamic here i can't convert it to camelcase using json.net. Is there any sql way of returning camelcase column names from sql server 2016

Answer (score 2):

They want this json output from "select ... for json auto":

[{"id":3,"sId":"5801","name":"pizza","type":"Error"}]

If you're using the SQL output directly in javascript, you might care that it's not camel case. However, in the above code, the SQL is being used in a .NET program, and .NET deserialization is not case sensitive. There's no need to use dynamic types or mess with serializer settings. Just deserialize directly to `SomeClass`:

`var someClass = JSONConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(dataArray)`

But note that you should use C# conventions in C# code -- so SomeClass should be using Pascal case names. If you're returning SomeClass from a .NET WebApi, *that's* when you should convert to camel case. In .NET Core this is done by default. For .NET Framework, you can change JSON serializer setting at app init time to do the same thing.

But if you really want:

`[{"id":3,"sId":"5801","name":"pizza","type":"Error"}]`

modify the query itself if you can and explicitly list the columns in whatever case you want:

`select id, sId, name, type from ... for json auto`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a stored procedure to do the conversion of arbitrary JSON to camelcase. It covers most data types that I can think of, but there could be some JSON that would break it. I'd love to have it be a function, but you can't do dynamic sql in a function.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CamelCaseJson] (
    @jsonIn nvarchar(max),
    @jsonOut nvarchar(max) output
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @isArray    BIT = 0
    DECLARE @innerCols  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @outerCols  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF LEFT(@jsonIn, 1) = '['
    BEGIN
        SET @isArray = 1
    END

    CREATE TABLE #tmpData (
        [rownum]            INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
        [key]               NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [value]             NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [type]              INT,
        [processedKey]      NVARCHAR(MAX),
        [processedValue]    NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    DECLARE @jsons TABLE (
        [rownum]    INT,
        [json]      NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT #tmpData (
        [key],
        [value],
        [type],
        [processedKey],
        [processedValue]
    )
    SELECT
        [key],
        [value],
        [type],
        LOWER(SUBSTRING([key], 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING([key], 2, 999999999),
        [value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@jsonIn)  


    INSERT @jsons (
        [rownum],
        [json]
    )
    SELECT
        [rownum],
        [value]
    FROM #tmpData
    WHERE [type] in (4, 5)


    DECLARE @id         INT
    DECLARE @subJsonIn  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @subJsonOut NVARCHAR(MAX)
    
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @jsons)
    BEGIN
        SET @subJsonOut = NULL

        SELECT 
            TOP 1 
            @id = [rownum],
            @subJsonIn = [json]
        FROM @jsons

        EXEC [dbo].[CamelCaseJson] @subJsonIn, @subJsonOut OUTPUT

        UPDATE #tmpData
        SET [processedValue] = @subJsonOut
        WHERE [rownum] = @id

        DELETE @jsons WHERE [rownum] = @id
    end


    IF @isArray = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @innerCols = COALESCE(@innerCols + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME([processedKey]) FROM #tmpData

        SELECT @outerCols = 
            COALESCE(@outerCols + ', ', '') 
                +   CASE    
                        WHEN [type] = 2 AND [value] LIKE '%e%' THEN 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME([processedKey]) + ' AS FLOAT) AS ' + QUOTENAME([processedKey])
                        WHEN [type] = 2 AND [value] LIKE '%.%' THEN 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME([processedKey]) + ' AS DECIMAL(19, 7)) AS ' + QUOTENAME([processedKey])
                        WHEN [type] = 2 THEN 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME([processedKey]) + ' AS INT) AS ' + QUOTENAME([processedKey])
                        WHEN [type] = 3 THEN 'CAST(' + QUOTENAME([processedKey]) + ' AS BIT) AS ' + QUOTENAME([processedKey])
                        WHEN [type] in (4, 5) THEN 'JSON_QUERY(' + QUOTENAME([processedKey]) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME([processedKey])
                        ELSE QUOTENAME([processedKey]) 
                    END
        FROM #tmpData 


        SET @sql = '
            WITH pv AS (
                SELECT
                    [dummy] = 1,
                    [key] = [processedKey],
                    [value] = [processedValue]
                FROM #tmpData
            )
            SELECT @dynout = (
                SELECT ' + @outerCols + '
                FROM (
                    SELECT [dummy], ' + @innerCols + '
                    FROM pv
                    PIVOT (
                        MAX([value]) FOR [key] IN (' + @innerCols + ')
                    ) pvresult
                ) x
                FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
            )
        '

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@dynout NVARCHAR(MAX) OUT', @jsonOut OUTPUT
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @jsonOut = 
            COALESCE(@jsonOut + ',', '') + 
                CASE
                    WHEN [type] = 1 THEN '"' + [processedValue] + '"' 
                    ELSE [processedValue]
                END
        FROM #tmpData 
        ORDER BY [rownum]

        SET @jsonOut = '[' + @jsonOut + ']'
    END

    DROP TABLE #tmpData
END
GO
```

To check your example:

```
DECLARE @jsonIn     NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @jsonOut    NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @jsonIn = (
    SELECT
        [Id] = 3,
        [SId] = '5801',
        [Name] = 'Pizza',
        [Type] = 'Error'
    FOR JSON PATH
)

EXEC [dbo].[CamelCaseJson] @jsonIn, @jsonOut OUTPUT

SELECT @jsonIn [Json]
UNION ALL
SELECT @jsonOut [Json]
```

gives you

> In    [{"Id":3,"SId":"5801","Name":"Pizza","Type":"Error"}]
>
> Out   [{"id":3,"sId":"5801","name":"Pizza","type":"Error"}]

My unit test JSON (not pretty formatted, sorry):

```
{"Pnull":null,"Pstring":"Foo","Pint":1,"Pdec":1.3,"Pbool":true,"Pstrarray":["a","b"],"Pintarray":[1,3,5],"Parray":[{"Prop":"val1"},{"Prop":"val2"}],"Pjson":{"Subproperty":1},"Pjsonstring":"{\"Subproperty\":2}","Poffset":"2017-06-20T22:18:31.2279221-04:00","DeepObj":{"Level":2,"Sub":{"Level":3,"Sub":{"Level":4,"Sub":{"Level":"Basement"}}}},"Flt":1.3e-9}
```